# doctrine 2 create database and tables

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create DB and tables, I am using Doctrine 2 without Symfony.

I am using this code:

```
$schemaTool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);
$classes = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
$schemaTool->createSchema($classes);
```

this code works to create the tables, but if I run this code without creating the database first, i got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database
```

how can I create de database with doctrine 2, in code php.

thanks

Comment: I had see this before, but i need to do in code and not in command. thanks. sorry for my English.

Comment: As the topic say: how about setting the db name to null?

Comment: yes, but i am not using zend-framework 2, where can i configurate this. i just downloaded the doctrine with composer.phar. thanks